# Maven surefire plugin doesn't fail on test broken due to spring context

Tags: spring, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm running `mvn verify` on my project that contains a lot of unit and integration tests.
During the verify execution some of these tests fails because spring cannot create the context (due to a missing bean).
Maven verify execution proceed and the results was success because no tests are run inside these failing test class.
Is it possible to force the build to fail also when a test class fails the initializazion?